# Cannot push/pull folders from Master to GitHub

Tags: git, github

I've tried following the instructions from GitHub as well as instructions from previous posts but I cannot seem to upload my project to github.

Backstory: I deleted the repo that I first initalized my project with on github and I created a new one. I was making commits, but I never pushed them to GitHub. To upload my project I ran this:

```
git remote rm origin
```

```
git remote add origin <new URL>
```

and it worked with no errors. When I try this

```
git push -u master
```

I get the error:

```
fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I've also tried to use the GitHub web interface to upload my project but it doesn't upload my .git file, even if it isn't hidden.

Comment: Did you mean to push master to origin?

Comment: You need to supply a *remote* there, not a *branch*.

Comment: @evolutionxbox if origin means the github repo, then yes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so the correct method is git push -u origin?

Comment: See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Comment: @jonrsharpe I pushed my commits to GitHub and most of my files show up. However I cannot find my .git folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed adding `origin` in your command. Use the following to push your code:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it normal that my .git folder didn’t upload to github?

Comment: yes, even if you try `git status` , you will never see that this folder has updated or not, this is for your local machine purpose